# jsPdf using html2canvas.js: Uncaught Error: Supplied data is not a JPEG

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using jsPDF and html2Canvas to generate a PDF.

It works if I target the document.body.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pdfDownload() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  pdf.addHTML(document.body, function () {
  pdf.save('test.pdf');
  });
}</script>
```

However if I try to use an id on a div #pdfcontent I get:

"Uncaught Error: Supplied data is not a JPEG"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pdfDownload() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  pdf.addHTML($('#pdfcontent')[0], function () {
  pdf.save('test.pdf');
  });
}</script>
```

Help please

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, these days have updated jsPDF and does not work well with html2canvas.

I could not fix the problem (Sorry for not helping), but stopped using html2canvas by a plugin (for table elements in my case jsPDF-AutoTable) [jsPDF-AutoTable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable))